# Вопрос по Array.from({length: n}? Что значит {}

Tags: javascript

Решал задачки на codewars и в лучших решениях увидел, такое. Но, возник вопрос, что означают фигурные скобки `Array.from({length: n}` нигде не могу найти информацию.

```
function towerBuilder(n) {
  return Array.from({length: n}, function(v, k) {
    const spaces = ' '.repeat(n - k - 1);
    return spaces + '*'.repeat(k + k + 1) + spaces;
  });
}
```

Comment: странно, но в документации https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from  всё написано

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, там указанно, первым параметром принимает Массивоподобный или итерируемый объект, преобразуемый в массив. Но, {length: n} не дает мне покоя) ведь это не n.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скобки обозначают объект. По спецификации данный объект должен иметь свойство `length`, второй аргумент (опциональный) - map-функция, которая проходит по каждому элементу массива (изначально `undefined`). Третий опциональный аргумент который принимает Array.from - необходимый `this` для map-функции. Пример:

```js
const objectWithLength = {length : 3}
const a = Array.from(objectWithLength);

objectWithLength.length = 4;
const mapFunction = (item, idx) => idx + 1;
const b = Array.from(objectWithLength, mapFunction);

console.log('a', a);
console.log('b', b);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да нашел в статье теперь)